# iOS5 File Sharing: recognize when files have been added to a Directory?

Tags: ipad, synchronization, itunes, ios5, file-sharing

as the title says i wanna know how i can recognize that new file have been added to my App for example over an iTunes Sync. In iOS4 i used the methods

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

or

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didBecomeActive
```

But since iOS 5, this is useless because the app will not enter the Background and become active after a sync. It stays active. So is there a way to solve this?

regards

Ralf

Answer (score 2):

If iTunes file sharing uses the new file coordination mechanism (haven't checked but I would assume that it does), you could implement the `NSFilePresenter` protocol to get notified of changes in the Documents directory.

It should be possible to use a single file presenter for the entire directory by implementing `presentedSubitemDidAppearAtURL:` and related methods (see "Handling Changes to a Presented Directory" in the [`NSFilePresenter` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFilePresenter_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)).

Comment: -.- Ok. Shame on me that i didn´t see that in the Doc. Sounds great. Thanks omz

Comment: @RaleKay Did you ever get to try this? I just attempted to implement my suggestion and while it works fine in the simulator when I drop files into the simulator's Documents directory, I don't get any notifications on the device when I use iTunes file sharing. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if iTunes just doesn't use file coordination (in which case it might be worth filing a bug).

Comment: From [this thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/517775) in the dev forums, it seems that iTunes really doesn't use file coordination. :(

Comment: Hi. Sorry for my late respond. Jap i did get it to work but without the protocol. I just did start a request if there are any new files in the documents directory in a background thread. It´s exactly the the same as the protocol should work. But without the protocol you got it for pre iOS5 Devices, too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I create a Timer and periodically check for new files in the Directory shared with ITunes. I think with iOS5 it's the best approach.

iOS5 can sync through WiFi so you don't have control about when a file will be added to the directory